# gcc не компилирует override

Tags: c++, наследование, полиморфизм, language-lawyer, override

```
struct override {};

struct A {
    virtual override override() = 0;
};

struct B : A {
    auto override() -> struct override override{
        return ::override{};
    }
};

int main() {
    B().override();
}
```

Почему `clang` компилирует без проблем, а `gcc` - нет? Кто прав и почему?

> error: declaration of 'virtual override A::override()' changes meaning
> of 'override'

Также интересно, нужен ли `::` и почему. Никто не хочет компилировать без него.

> error: reference to non-static member function must be called; did you
> mean to call it with no arguments?

Comment: а где такие вопросы задают?

Comment: @KoVadim составляю собесы

Comment: нет, нельзя такое задавать. если попадут мои ученики, то вынесут:)

Comment: за что минус вопросу?

Comment: Если разные компиляторы компилируют код по-разному, то мне кажется это явный признак, что это не надо спрашивать на собесах. Если вы не разработчиков компиляторов С++ собеседуете... Я бы не ответил. И я прям уверен, что никто из моих коллег не ответил бы, и никто из тех, кого я собеседовал...

Comment: ну о том, что override и final полуключевые слова у меня даже джуны знают. Они такой код бы с наскока не взяли, но объяснили, что так писать не стоит

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это код с собеседования? Не стоит использовать полуключевое слово (override) как имя функции и имя структуры одновременно. Ни к чему хорошему это не приведет. В данном случае компилятор gcc об этом явно и предупреждает. Но если очень-очень хочется выстрелить себе в ногу в будущем, то пока можно это спрятать, явно подсказав компилятору, что там именно такое

```
struct A {
    virtual struct override override() = 0;
};
```

Но не пишите такое в продакшн код и не показывайте на собеседованиях.

Но на самом деле здесь ошибка просто мастерски спрятана (если бы меня таким кодом собеседовали, я бы встал и вышел (и я так делал, очень рекомендую!)). Можно смело override заменить на test и будет такая же ошибка.

Есть такая цитата в стандарте [3.3.7 Class Scope]

> A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

Если кратко - одно и тоже имя в пределах класса должно значить одно и тоже. Но от компилятора не требуется диагностика.

Поэтому gcc прав, он знает, что программа плохая и говорит об этом (хотя и не должен был этого делать).

clang не говорит о том, что программа плохая (но и не должен был), но при этом скомпилировал программу.

двойное двоеточие в `return ::override{};` нужно, что бы компилятор догадался, что здесь именно внешнее имя, а не имя функции или ещё что то.

Comment: спасибо, но хотелось бы увидеть ответы на вопросы из вопроса

Comment: то есть, Вы хотите узнать, должен ли этот код компилироваться по стандарту?

Comment: да, и есть ли баг в компиляторах. И ещё вопрос добавил

Comment: нет, ошибки формально нет.

Comment: "здесь именно внешнее имя, а не имя функции или ещё что то" -- но об этом же говорит `{}`, т.е. это не может быть функция и не может быть ключевое слово, неоднозначностей нет даже без `::`

Comment: да, плюсовый компилятор иногда умеет делать парсинг с возвратом (Вы именно этого от него и хотите), но это не всегда возможно.  К тому же в этом месте нарушается то же самое правило 3.3.7. Но если имена привести в порядок (то есть, сделать разными), то все компилируется без ::

Comment: _Если кратко - одно и тоже имя в пределах класса должно значить одно и тоже... Поэтому gcc прав_ GCC не прав, т.к. имя значит одно и то же. Лукап идентификатора в elaborated-type-specifier (`override` в `struct override`) игнорирует все объявления не-типов. GCC же считает что объявление функции с именем `override` повлияет на то, что бы нашлось для `override` в `struct override`, происходи поиск в полном определении класса (где функция с именем `override` уже объявлена).

Comment: oops, ну я и лоханулся. Я думал речь про то, что gcc прав насчёт `virtual struct override override`, а не `virtual override override`. Надеюсь, модераторы почистят, чтобы никого не смущать.